# Windows phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight

I'm new to windows phone development..How to create a gridview in windows phone 8.1 silverlight. When i'm trying create grid view in my app,i'm getting error
as follows"The name "Grid View" does not exist in the namespace"http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"...

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please share the code sample

Answer (score 0):

GridView control is not present in Windows phone silverlight. It is available in WinRT framework only.
I would recommend go for windows phone 8.1 XAML application(WinRT) and not for silverlight as support for silverlight is getting lesser day by day.